# Resetting pointer to the start of file

Tags: c, string, pointers

How would I be able to reset a pointer to the start of a commandline input or file. For example my function is reading in a line from a file and prints it out using getchar()

```
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        key[i++]=c;
        if(c == '\n' )
        {
            key[i-1] = '\0'
            printf("%s",key);
        }       
    }
```

After running this, the pointer is pointing to EOF im assuming? How would I get it to point to the start of the file again/or even re read the input file

im entering it as (./function < inputs.txt)

Comment: Just close and reopen the file

Comment: `EOF ` should be through `stdin` so what are you trying to reset .. If you were getting input from file then `rewind(fp)` would have worked

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you have a `FILE*` other than `stdin`, you can use:

```
rewind(fptr);
```

or

```
fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

to reset the pointer to the start of the file.

You cannot do that for `stdin`.

If you need to be able to reset the pointer, pass the file as an argument to the program and use `fopen` to open the file and read its contents.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int c;
   FILE* fptr;

   if ( argc < 2 )
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: program filename\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   fptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   if ( fptr == NULL )
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s\n", argv[1]);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

    while((c=fgetc(fptr))!=EOF)
    {
       // Process the input
       // ....
    }

    // Move the file pointer to the start.
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // Read the contents of the file again.
    // ...

    fclose(fptr);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Consider using fseek over rewind, since only fseek provides a return code for error checking: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-82/

Comment: 'fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);' worked for me on stdin. Is it unreliable or why did you say it doesn't work on stdin?

Comment: @daniswhoiam, I am going to guess that your platform provides functionality that is not guaranteed by the standard. `rewind` is equivalent to `std::fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_SET)`. The [documentation for `fseek`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fseek) indicates that a file stream is expected for `fseek` to work.

Answer (score 5):

Piped / redirected input doesn't work like that.  Your options are:

- Read the input into an internal buffer (which you already seem to be doing); or
- Pass the file name as a command-line argument instead, and do with it as you please.