# Counting Character usage in text file? C

Tags: c, character, text-files, counter, toupper

**Hi,** 
I need to count the usage of alphabetical characters in some plain text file. This is what i have came with. Basically just run through the text file and compare each character with the ASCII value of specific searched character. 
When I run it, all I can see is just the first `printf()` string and just error of terminated status when I close the console. 
I do have a text.txt file in same folder as the .exe file but I can't see anything.

Not sure if just my syntax is bad or even semantics. 
Thx for help! :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ASCIIstart 65 
#define ASCIIend 90

void main(){
    FILE *fopen(), *fp;
    int c;
    unsigned int sum;

    fp = fopen("text.txt","r");

    printf("Characters found in text: \n");

    for (int i = ASCIIstart; i <= ASCIIend; i++){
        sum = 0;
        c = toupper(getc(fp));
        while (c != EOF){
            if (c == i){
                sum = sum++;
            }
            c = toupper(getc(fp));
        }
        if (sum > 0){
            printf("%c: %u\n",i,sum);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: If you use the library function `isalpha` you won't have to worry about hard-coding magic numbers, or case. You will need to `#include <ctype.h>`

Comment: Why are you doing `sum = sum++;`? Don't you think `sum++` would have been enough?

Comment: What magic numbers are you talking about?
sorry im a little noob in C programming :/
-
Its an habit from school where we have to use this in Pascal

Comment: why are you declaring fopen() ?

Comment: don't you think your for loop should be inside the while loop rather than being outside?

Comment: Its now working, thanks alot for all your help!
Now i will just have to figure out what was the main issue, other than me.
Thx ! ;-)

Comment: also, perhaps a better method would be to recognize that you have exactly 26 letters in the alphabet :P

Comment: -Ahmed Masud
-TBH im not sure what ive done, ive seen it in an online tutorial and just used it, is there any other way?
-I dont know, this was my first idea to do it without having to store the value and printing them in alphabetical order :-) in case you though of another solution, im opened to new ideas

Comment: @RollAndSchullz I mean the magic numbers `65` and `90`. ASCII is common but not universal.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah but then i would not know what the character is, would i?.. i havent thought much about this problem and as i said, this is the first solution that i came up with, but thanks for the tip :-)

Comment: @AhmedMasud yeah i know how many letters are in alphabet, but using this i can search for various symbols in ASCII

Comment: @RollAndSchullz you would: it is the value read.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rewind the pointer to the beginning of the file at the end of your for loop?

This has been posted before: [Resetting pointer to the start of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366665/resetting-pointer-to-the-start-of-file)

P.S. - maybe use an array for your output values : int charactercount[pow(2,sizeof(char))] so that you don't have to parse the file repeatedly?

*edit: was missing pow()*

Comment: Still not working,
i changed ti by adding this at the end of every for cycle...
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET)
but still nothing other than the first printf.

And is the way im doing it, without an array, problematic? Can it cause some issues?

Comment: It will make your execution time o(n^2) instead of o(n).  Also, if you use an array, you would only need to make one pass.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking up the entire file for each character, you could do

```
FILE *fp;
int c, sum[ASCIIend - ASCIIstart + 1]={0};
fp = fopen("file.txt,"r");
if(fp==NULL)
{
    perror("Error");
    return 1;
}

int i;
while( (c = toupper(getc(fp)))!= EOF)
{
    if(c>=ASCIIstart && c<=ASCIIend)
    {
        sum[c-ASCIIstart]++;
    }
}
for(i=ASCIIstart; i<=ASCIIend; ++i)
{
    printf("\n%c: %d", i, sum[i-ASCIIstart]);
}
```

You must check the return value of `fopen()` to ensure that the file was successfully opened.

There's an array `sum` which holds the the number of occurrences of each character within the range denoted with `ASCIIend` and `ASCIIstart` macros.

The size of the array is just the number of characters whose number of occurrences is to be counted.

`sum[c-ASCIIstart]` is used because the difference between the ASCII value (if the encoding is indeed ASCII) of `c` and `ASCIIstart` would give the index associated with `c`.

I don't know what you meant with `FILE *fopen(), fp;` but `fopen()` is the name of a function in C used to open files.

And by

```
FILE *fopen(), *fp;
```

you gave a prototype of a function `fopen()`.

But in `stdio.h`, there's already a prototype for `fopen()` like

```
FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);
```

yet no errors (if so) were shown because `fopen()` means that the function can have any number of arguments. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032/is-there-a-difference-between-foovoid-and-foo-in-c-or-c).

Had the return type of your `FILE *fopen();` were not `FILE *` or if it were shown to other parameter types like `int`, you would definitely have got an error.

And, `void main()` is not considered good practice. Use `int main()` instead. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/207992/5375464).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a character array and parse the file contents with one time traversal and display the array count finally.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void main(){
FILE *fopen(), *fp;
int c;
fp = fopen("test.txt","r");
printf("Characters found in text: \n");
char charArr[26]= {0};
c = toupper(fgetc(fp));

while(c!=EOF) {
  charArr[c-'A']=charArr[c-'A']+1;
  c = toupper(fgetc(fp));
}
fclose(fp);
for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
   printf("\nChar: %c | Count= %d ",i+65,charArr[i]);
}
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

because after first time you are end of the file.
and your  c = toupper(getc(fp)); returning -1 after that.

Comment: Oh i see..

So should i use...while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)... and add an if statement?

Answer (score 0):

For counting just one character, you are reading the whole file and repeating this for each and every character. Instead, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define ASCIIstart 65 
#define ASCIIend 90

int main(){
    FILE  *fp;
    int c, i;
    int alphabets[26] = {0};

    fp = fopen("text.txt","r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to open file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while ((c = toupper(fgetc(fp))) != EOF){
        if (c >= ASCIIstart && c <= ASCIIend)
            alphabets[c - ASCIIstart]++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fprintf(stdout, "Characters found in text: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        fprintf (stdout, "%c: %d\n", i+ASCIIstart, alphabets[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR

Working with your code, your loops are inside-out.

I'll answer in pseudo-code to keep the concepts straightforward.

Right now you are doing this:

```
 FOR LETTER = 'A' TO 'Z': 
      WHILE FILE HAS CHARACTERS
           GET NEXT CHARACTER
           IF CHARACTER == LETTER 
                ADD TO COUNT FOR CHAR
           END IF
      END WHILE
 END FOR
```

The problem is you are running through the file with character 'A' and then reaching the end of file so nothing gets done for 'B'...'Z'

If you swapped this:

```
 WHILE FILE HAS CHARACTERS
      GET NEXT CHARACTER 
          FOR LETTER = 'A' TO 'Z'
              IF LETTER = UCASE(CHARACTER)
                   ADD TO COUNT FOR LETTER
              END IF
          END FOR
 END WHILE
```

Obviously doing 26 checks for each letter is too much so perhaps a better approach.

```
 LET COUNTS = ARRAY(26) 

 WHILE FILE HAS CHARACTERS
         CHARACTER := UCASE(CHARACTER)
         IF CHARACTER >= 'A' AND CHARACTER <= 'Z'
            LET INDEX = CHARACTER - 'A'
            COUNTS[INDEX]++
         ENDIF
 END WHILE
```

You can translate the pseudo code to C as an exercise.